# Sending NLog logs to the server through WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, nlog

I have one server and many client applications, NLog is used everywhere. The purpose is to nearly completely remove logs from client and  to send logs from a client directly to the server. It's successfully done through WCF, `ILogReceiverServer` and `LogReceiverService` target (as written [there](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/LogReceiverService-target)).

But the connection between server and client apps could be lost, so it's necessary to write `Error` messages to the file on the client side. And it should be written only when the connection is lost. <s>I've studied NLog docs</s> (should've studied better), but haven't found anything. Is it possible to check if logs were sent successfully or not? Or, may be, to enable/disable `logger` based on the result of logs sending?

Client config:

```xml
  <nlog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets>
      <target name="file" xsi:type="File" ... />
      <target name="console" xsi:type="Console" ... />
      <target xsi:type="LogReceiverService"
        name="RemoteWcfLogger"
        endpointConfigurationName="NetTcpBinding_ILogReceiverServer"
        endpointAddress="net.tcp://address:port/LogReceiverServer"
        useBinaryEncoding="True"
        clientId=""
        includeEventProperties="True">
      </target>
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minLevel="Trace" writeTo="RemoteWcfLogger"/>
      <logger name="*" minLevel="Error" writeTo="file" />
      <logger name="*" minLevel="Trace" writeTo="console" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the Nlog FallbackGroup-target could be a solution:

https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/FallbackGroup-target

So when the primary-target fails, then it will fallback to a secondary target.

Comment: Seems like I've missed it, exactly what I want. It can also be done through custom conditions though.